# Remove item from an Array when clicking in a option

Tags: javascript, arrays, click

I have a Javascript array named `activeFilters` with the following values:

```
var activeFilters = [
    ['Tom Brady', 'Aaron Rodgers', 'Patrick Mahomes'],
    ['Post Game', 'Status']
];
```

I also have a menu list with all the values gathered in an unordered list:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Tom Brady</li>
    <li>Post Game</li>
    <li>Aaron Rodgers</li>
    <li>Patrick Mahomes</li>
    <li>Status</li>
</ul>
```

My main goals is: when users click in one of the `<li>` options to remove this value from the array.

Comment: .....but keep it inside the UL?

Comment: Well, the respective <li> will be also removed, but I can sorte it in a loop (since the value is no longer in the array).

Comment: Why don't you rebuild your list using a flattened array using `activeFilters.flat()` ?

Comment: Because the main array contains two "sub arrays". As can be seen, one contains name of the players and the another contains the categories. So all of them are "flatted" in the `<ul>`, however, I need to remove the respective into the according internal array.

Comment: Sure, that is lost in the way your _using_ the strings. It is one list. An Array by definition is a _list_ - The structure of one list should match the other. `activeFilters.flat().filter(f=>f!==clickedOnItemText)` is the solution.

Comment: The array filter method returns the filtered list. Perhaps the compromise would be to name the original array `filters` and the filtered array `activeFilters`. The `activeFilter` array would be the _working_ list while persevering the structure of the original.

Comment: Yes, this is fine! However, my main goal is to remove the value from the array. I am not concerned with how the `<ul>` will render the list, but how the array will be updated without that value selected.

Comment: Why would you want to end up with `[[],[]]` after all items are removed? I'm afraid you're not asking the right question... :\

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var activeFilters = [
    ['Tom Brady', 'Aaron Rodgers', 'Patrick Mahomes'],
    ['Post Game', 'Status']
];
// Select all the lis 
const lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");
lis.forEach((li) => {
 // Add event listener on each one of them with the callback function
  li.addEventListener("click",function() {
// Flat your arrays
    activeFilters = activeFilters.flat();
// Get the text from clicked li
    const textToRemoveFromArray = this.textContent;
   // Get the index in the array of the name
   const indexOfClickedName = activeFilters.findIndex((name) => textToRemoveFromArray === name);
// Splice from array at the index position, 1
   activeFilters.splice(indexOfClickedName,1);
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const activeFilters = [
  ['Tom Brady', 'Aaron Rodgers', 'Patrick Mahomes'],
  ['Post Game', 'Status']
];

const removeActiveFilterItem = (evt) => {
  const name = evt.currentTarget.textContent.trim();
  activeFilters.forEach((arr) => {
    const i = arr.findIndex(x => x === name);
    if (i > -1) arr.splice(i, 1);
  });
  console.log(activeFilters);
  evt.currentTarget.remove(); // Finally remove LI Element 
}

const EL_ListLIs = document.querySelectorAll("#list li");
EL_ListLIs.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", removeActiveFilterItem));
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Tom Brady</li>
  <li>Post Game</li>
  <li>Aaron Rodgers</li>
  <li>Patrick Mahomes</li>
  <li>Status</li>
</ul>
```

The above will not work if you have duplicate items inside the same sub-array. If that's the case that is' an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).